# Angular 8 routing rewrite fails

Tags: angular, angular-routing, azure-ad-msal

I have an app that uses MSAL.js for Azure B2C authentication. So it follows a regular OAuth 2.0 implicit flow to auth the user - when user clicks on a Login button it gets redirected to "authorize" endpoint, then the user is redirected back to the app upon successful login.

And here's the problem - the reply request comes as follows:

> > https://localhost:4200/run#state=dc81c410-4cbd-4218-bc78-9c5b5e9bebe5&client_info={...}

In order to make it work I have to rewrite this Url to `run/state`, so the resulting Url would be:

> > https://localhost:4200/run/state=f5f2c20f-ed72-4631-b834-80bf60aa6cd7&client_info={...}

And this is done in `AppComponent.ngInit`:

```
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/run#state/)) {
          const newUrl = event.url.replace("run#state", "run/state");
          console.warn(`newUrl = ${newUrl}`);
          this.router.navigate([newUrl]);
        }
      }
    });
```

Now I see the rewrite in the logs.

But the problem is it redirects to root now. From the log:

- `NavigationStart` for `run/state`
- URL REWRITE (but this time nothing to rewrite already, it's `run/state` now)
- "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."
- "Processing the callback from redirect response" - `MSAL.js callback function`
- "CHECK USER" - from `CanLoad` guard (which is simply returns `true` for now)
- `RouteConfigLoadStart`
- **Navigated to https://localhost:4200/**  BOOM!!!

Why on Earth does it redirect to root?

One important thing - if I navigate to:

> > https://localhost:4200/run/state=04e49903-1510-47da-9b24-cee988229d16&client_info={...}

in the browser, it does open that route (no redirects!).

**The repo is [on github](https://github.com/alvipeo/ng8-callback).**

The console:
[image]

Comment: Do you have route configured in one of your routing modules for `/run/state`? If so, is it for a component or is it a `redirectTo`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's a component.

Comment: It looks like it routes to root immediately after CheckUser. Are you certain that the routeguard is returning `true` under all scenarios in `canLoad`?

Comment: yes, it's just `return true;` line.

Comment: added link to the repo

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a full window reload is taking place. I think it has to do with the oidc config and callback handling. Will look at those docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201922/discussion-between-christian-and-alvipeo).

Answer (score -1):

- If You need to route (rewrite) on route/state  you should try this,

  `this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/run#state/)) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => 
        this.router.navigate(['/run/state']));
      }
    }
  });`

  I hope It Will work for you

Comment: Tried that. Same result.